# Meteor won't run jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm trying to run a block of jQuery code that shows and hides a form, but can't find a way to get Meteor to run the code on the client side. Here's the code I'm attempting to use at the moment:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.post.onRendered(function(){
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.replybtn').click(function(){
          if( $(this).parent().next().css('display') === 'none' ){
            $(this).parent().next().css('display', 'block');
          } else {
            $(this).parent().next().css('display', 'none');
          }
        });
      });
    });
}
```

I've also tried putting the code in a script tag, which did not work. Strangely, the jQuery portion of the code alone works fine when pasted into the browser console - meaning the bug is likely in how I'm running the code in Meteor, not the jQuery itself. Also, I've confirmed that the template name is correct and can't think of any other issues that could be causing this. Any ideas on why the jQuery code may not be running?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the best solution, but it appears that this issue can be fixed by defining a function that creates the event listener and then setting a 2 second timeout to run the function with *setTimeout()*.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to apply a traditional jQuery pattern when Meteor provides a simple facility to attach event handlers to templates. Here would be the meteoric way:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.post.events({
    '.replybtn click'(e){
      const selector = e.target.parentElement.nextSibling;
      selector.css('display', selector.css('display') === 'none'? 'block' : 'none');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: pretty sure css isn't a function in Meteor, I get a `Uncaught TypeError: selector.css is not a function` (Also, .parent and .next weren't functions so I used `const selector = e.target.parentElement.nextSibling;`)

Comment: ok, fixed code. `.css` is not a Meteor function but Meteor loads jQuery so you can use jQuery functions on the client.